# React Native: Facebook Like on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, react-native

My question is simple: I have a react native app that loads articles using WebView. Inside this WebView there is a like button that loads through the JS SDK.

However, when I'm pressing on the like button and logging in, I encounter a blank page.

Any ideas for this?

JSX:

```
<WebView
      ref="ArticleWebView"
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={false}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      source={{uri: webViewURL}}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      renderLoading={this.renderLoadingView}
      scrollEnabled={true}
/>
```

JS on the WebView:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : fbappid,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="' . get_permalink($ID) . '" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Comment: Post edited with code...

Comment: did u resolved this?